# Failed Audit- post deleted by community doesn't look low quality to me

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I was reviewing low quality posts and I marked *looks ok* an answer which is deemed too low quality and deleted by community... For the sake of me I cannot understand why.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10115536

The question states :

> need to view the transaction logs of a database on sql server 2008 in order to find a delete transaction and hopefully roll it back.
>
> Unfortunately I have no clue where to start, and I'm finding it difficult to determine which are good articles on google.
>
> Can anyone point me in the right direction?
>
> Thanks

The deleted post provide an undocumented function as solution, a brief explanation and a link for further explanation (***which I've read***). The accepted answer, well voted, is also about an undocumented function.

What's even more puzzling is that the answer is marked as spam or offensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (now deleted) user that posted that had also posted quite a few other answers all including the same link. It looks like a moderator decided it was a case of the user spamming their blog (without any other positive contribution to the site) and took action.

While it's not a *great* answer, there is some potentially useful information in there, so it's not completely unsalvageable and since the user is deleted it's difficult for anyone to get any context to know why it was spamming.

Since the other answers convey the same information, I've cleared the spam flags, and re-deleted the answer so it won't be appearing as an audit again.

Comment: It was junk. It added nothing that hadn't been posted **years** earlier, and was just promoting the answerer's blog.